# What is the proper capabilities to setup android chrome browser in Appium 1.15.1?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, appium-android

I'm trying to launch chrome browser on emulator but not able to do so. I tried with below capabilities but its going in hung state.

```
{
  "deviceName": "Pixel 2 API 28",
  "udid": "emulator-5554",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "9.0",
  "automationName": "UiAutomator1",
  "androidPackage": "com.android.chrome",
  "browserName": "Chrome",
  "unicodeKeyboard": true,
  "resetKeyboard": true
}
```

Comment: Hi Sudip, I would like to see more logs. My initial guess is chromedriver may not be present in your local.

Comment: yes correct. Chromedriver was not there. but while trying to install the same in appium same is not being installed. I guess there are some compatibility issue in chromedriver and appium version.

Comment: If anyone can help me with the setup required to automate the mobile browser that would help.

Comment: Chromedriver needs to installed separately if the current browser version is latest. Appium won't auto install new chromedrivers. More logs would help in setting up.

Comment: [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1582096445280 (12:44:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Trying to use a chromedriver binary at the path chromedriver, but it doesn't exist!
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Object.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:74:35)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Chromedriver.start (C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\lib\chromedriver.js:569:11)

Comment: add this desired capability - 'chromedriverExecutable' = "/pathto/chromedriver"

Comment: {
  "deviceName": "Pixel 2 API 28",
  "udid": "emulator-5554",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "9.0",
  "automationName": "UiAutomator1",
  "browserName": "Chrome",
  "chromedriverExecutable": "/C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/chromedriver",
  "unicodeKeyboard": true,
  "resetKeyboard": true
}

Comment: do u want me to pass like above ?

Comment: I hope that is the latest chromedriver that you have downloaded.

Comment: i've downloaded chromedriver 2.44 which supports the chrome browser installed in emulator

Comment: Still getting this error.. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Trying to use a chromedriver binary at the path /C:/Users/******/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/chromedriver, but it doesn't exist!

Comment: This issue has been resolved. chromedriver.exe need to place under appium path.

C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_modules\\appium\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\

and same has been passed in Desired Capabilities. Post that Chrome launched.

  "chromedriverExecutable": "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Appium\\resources\\app\\node_

Comment: Chromedriver can be put anywhere just that the same path has to be there in desired caps.